# evaluation of python list comprehensions

Tags: python, optimization, list-comprehension

I have a list comprehension that I hope is more performant than it's for loop equivalent. However, I am unsure how python evaluates comprehensions. If it evaluates breadth first, then the operation is ver expensive, however, it seems feasible to evaluate them all at each step, only requiring the data to be evaluated once and passed up through the loops. The list comprehension I am wondering about is below.

```
[(Counter(x.keys()), x) for x in [Counter([hashxx(w)%100000 for w in n.split()]) for n in x]]
```

How would this be evaluated? would the hash be calculated and then bubble up to the outer loop or would all the hashes be calculated first?

Comment: I believe you can do [`generator expressions`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), replacing the square brackets in inner list comprehensions with parenthesis, this way you get the inner expressions evaluating as you go, one at a time.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing now, but I am interested to know how python comprehensions are evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension is always fully evaluated where it occurs, just like any other expression like `a+b`.  The list comprehension does not "know" that it is inside another list comprehension, so it can't behave any differently on that basis.

If you want to iterate "bit by bit", generating only one item from the list comprehension at a time, then use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Here is a simple comparison:

```
def inner(x):
    print("inner")
    return x.upper()

def outer(x):
    print("outer")
    return x+"!"

# inner comprehension is a list comprehension
>>> [outer(x) for x in [inner(x) for x in ('a', 'b', 'c')]]
inner
inner
inner
outer
outer
outer
['A!', 'B!', 'C!']

# inner comprehension is a generator comprehension
>>> [outer(x) for x in (inner(x) for x in ('a', 'b', 'c'))]
inner
outer
inner
outer
inner
outer
['A!', 'B!', 'C!']
```